# No module named pytesseract

Tags: python, ubuntu, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to use pytesseract in my code (running Ubuntu), and start by importing it.

I get an error saying: ImportError: No module named pytesseract
This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pytesseract.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pytesseract
ImportError: No module named pytesseract
```

I have installed pytesseract, and looked at many other posts trying what they have suggested but no luck. From what I have read it may have something to do with path variables?

As I said, I have tried many different suggestions on other posts but have not had any luck. I am new to Ubuntu and tesseract in general.

Thanks

Comment: will you show us the output of sys.path ?

Comment: How did you install it? Do you use multiple envs? Maybe a `pip`/`pip3` problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have done

```
pip install pytesseract
```

Then you should be able to import it.  If you have been working in a virtual environment before then activate the environment and then run

```
pip install pytesseract
```

To definitely know that it is installed

```
git clone https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract.git
```

Navigate to your local clone and then pip install the local directory of pytesseract.
Let's say I cloned it to my Desktop.

```
pip install /home/scrubster/pytesseract/
```

You could always point to it by setting up a path in your ~./bashrc file.  However, I don't recommend it since it has a setup.py file and is installable via pip.